# Ring of invariants for graph automorphism

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, graph-theory, invariant-theory, automorphism-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$Let $G$ be a finite simple graph with nodes numbered $1$ to $n$. Attach variables $x_1, ..., x_n$ to nodes. The graph automorphism group $\Aut G$ acts on nodes by permutations, hence induces action on variables $x_1, .., x_n$. The ring of invariants
$$\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]^{\Aut G}$$
is finitely generated by Noether Theorem.

**Question:** Is there an upper bound on degrees of generators in terms of $n$?

For example, for complete graph on $n$ vertices $K_n$, the automorphism group is $S_n$ and we recover usual symmetric polynomials
$$\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]^{S_n} = \mathbb{C}[\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_n]$$

**Remark:** For general subgroup of $S_n$ the upper bound on degree is known to be $n(n-1)/2$. The bound is attained by Vandermonde determinant since it is one of generators for alternating group $A_n$.

But subgroups of $S_n$ given by graph automorphism have significant restrictions. They can be thought of as permutations that fix certain 2-tensor or just polynomial
$$q(G) = \sum_{(i, j) \in E} x_i x_j.$$

Comment: Link to the MSE post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4567334/polynomial-ring-of-invariants-and-graphs

Comment: Do you have code to compute the degrees, ideally for SageMath (or perhaps Gap)?

Comment: Never mind, I have found a way using singular.  The statistic "maximal degree of the generators for a given graph" was unknown to findstat, so I added it.  The maximal value of the statistic appears to be $n$, and is attained for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_graph

Comment: @MartinRubey Thank you for this statistic, very insightful. This means the question can be refined to a conjecture "degrees are upper bounded by $n$ and the equality is attained only when automorphism group contains a cyclic subgroup $C_n$ acting transitively on vertices". My naive guess would be that this case is the only one when we need $x_1x_2...x_n$ as a generator.
It feels there should be a simple argument why higher degree generators are never needed.

Comment: The statistic is now available at https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/1844/

Comment: I know very little about generators of invariant rings, are there some further statistics (apart from the maximal degree) that would be interesting?

Comment: @MartinRubey I guess larger graphs can have more complicated Aut G structure. So up to 8 vertices are not hard cases. E.g. even $G = C_3$ appears only on larger graphs.

Comment: I'd be interested in a concrete counterexample!

Comment: I love this question. I would be surprised if the conjecture holds. The automorphism groups of bigger graphs will be more diverse. That said, if it does hold: one strategy would be to hope that the invariants of a graph automorphism group are generated by the orbit sums of squarefree monomials? (From which the bound would follow immediately.)